# Why does the any() function return False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having difficulty using the `all()` and `any()` functions.

I have the following code below where I check for two adjacent digits are the same. Though the output of the `print` statements is not what I expect.

From my understanding:

`any` will return `True` if any of the values are `True`, while
the `all` will only return `True` if all of the values are `True`

Writing and running the code using [Repl.it](https://repl.it)

```
test = 223456
number = str(test)
a = zip(number,number[1:])

#Checks for adjacent
equals = map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], a)

print(list(equals))    #OUTPUT: [True, False, False, False, False]
print(any(equals))     #OUTPUT: False
print(all(equals))     #OUTPUT: True
```

Comment: Truthy and Falsey, not the same as `True` and `False`. Add a print to your generator (the `map` and `zip`)  and see what it outputs. Does it output what you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already consumed `equals` on the first call to `list`, since `map` is like a generator:

```py
x = map(bool, range(1, 5))
print(list(x))
[True, True, True, True]
print(list(x))
[]
```

What you should do is convert it to a `list` or some data structure that allows you to iterate over it twice:

```py
equals = list(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], a))

print(any(equals)) # True
print(all(equals)) # False
```

Where `all` will return `True` on an empty collection:

```py
all([])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer covered, the main reason is that your `map` was already consumed prior to the `any()` and `all()` function.  If you don't want to create a `list` to store the data (e.g. if there's a large amount of data), you could do a parallel operation instead:

```
>>> print(any(equals), all(equals), sep='\n')
True
False
```

Or if you need to do something with those values:

```
>>> a, b = any(equals), all(equals)
>>> a
True
>>> b
False
```

Just to make it clear, both `zip` and `map` are both generators that get consumed once iterated.

Comment: Would the map be consumed if it were used in RETURN -statement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you mean `return map(...)` then no, it'll only return the `map` object.  But once you iterate or try to extract from the object i.e. `for m in map_object:` then it'll start the consumption.  You can limit the consumption if you use `next(map_object)` so that you only consume the data one at a time, but whatever was processed will be lost.

Comment: Let's say we have two functions using lambda and map:
`biggerThan = list(map(lambda x: x[0] <= x[1],a))` and 
`equals = list(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], a))`. What is needed in order to be able to return the value of both of these?

Comment: Since `a` is a `zip` object, you should first make it into a `list` like the other answer suggested.  Otherwise, you can do a parallel operation like mine, but it'll get much  more verbose.  If data is not huge making the list to store would be much simpler, but I'll update my answer to reflect your additional question.

Comment: Well, I tried using list, but it still printed empty list, so I ended up initialize two identical `zip` objects, `a` and `b`. Hmmm, ok. Thanks alot r.ook (and C.Nivs). Guess I'll have to read the docu - to become better

Comment: You'll need to make your `a` into a `list` first, i.e. `a = list(zip(number,number[1:])`.  That way you can always access the data in there.  Then you can think about making the other `map` into `list`s.

Comment: Ah, I see... That was not implicit for my understanding... Again, thanks you very much. 
Please share sites, books etc. you recommend.